# Shortcut icon problem in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser, favicon

For me, favicon is not appearing in FireFox 3.6 but is working in IE7.
In Firefox, when the page is loading I am able to see my favicon.
But once the page is completely loaded, I am not seeing my favicon.
And if I refresh my page, favicon re-appears.

Here is how I call my favicon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/eConcierge_win.ico" />
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to convey ??

Comment: Im saying icon is not displaying wen the page is completly loaded . Appearing oly after the refresh

Answer (score 8):

Just make sure to always put the favicon in the **root directory** of your site, and name it `favicon.ico`.

---

And please change your favicon like this

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Read this: [rel="shortcut icon" considered harmful](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon)

Comment: i tried with this too <link rel="icon" href="img/eConcierge_win.ico" />

Comment: Do u mean to say that its becos of the name of the image

Comment: @Jaisri_88, Yes. Change the name of the file to `favicon.ico` and place it in the root folder as yetanothercoder mentions in his answer. If you read the article in the answer that will explain why you need to do this.