# favicon not showing

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a favicon to my url-bar. But it's not showing up, I'm sure the path is correct because when I use it as a normal image it does show up. Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> title </title>
    <link href = "styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.png">
```

Comment: Browser? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870822/shortcut-icon-problem-in-firefox

Comment: Yeah I see now that it works in firefox but not in chrome and IE. Thanks for the thread will read it.

Comment: Hey, any luck? Did you get it working? I have the same issue.

Comment: If you host the contents on a local server, and if you access to it using URL which includes `localhost`, try to use a full IP address (e.g. `192.168.11.3`) rather than `localhost`. For example, not `http://localhost/index.html` but `http://192.168.11.3/index.html`. This worked like a charm in my case. (In my case, a favicon was not shown at all and `iframe` didn't work properly, all of which are now solved.)

Comment: Is there a reason why localhost does not work and having the actual ip itself works instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

First, try to give the full URL istead. For example `"http://localhost/mysite/images/favicon.png"` (adapt it to your configuration, actually)

Otherwise, on my site, this works:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
```

Try to:

1. convert your png to ico. There are free online tools, for example http://www.convertico.com/
2. be sure of your folder path. Won't be `./images` instead of `../images`? Try to give the full URL otherwise. For example `"http://localhost/mysite/images/favicon.ico"`.
3. after the above steps, try to clear the browser cache and reload the site.

Comment: Doesn't work as well with this.. It does work in firefox though

Answer (score 2):

use `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.png">`

See [W3C howto](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

> However, the format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used. My icon is 16x16 used this generator: http://www.favicon.cc/

Comment: Are you sure about the path `../images/favicon.png` ?

Comment: Yes Vodun, If I use it as img src or as background img in css it shows up.

Comment: No luck with that, strange bit is that it works in firefox and not in other browsers.. I deleted the cache etc. but still no luck

Comment: Try clearing your Cache between code updates (in most browsers, hit refresh + shift at the same time).  It will force the code to reload.

Answer (score -1):

Your `rel` attribute needs to be `icon` and not `shortcut icon`.

There are several ways to set a Favicon, but this is what I use:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?= base_url('assets/images/logos/favicon.png'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Ah yes i added the shortcut because I saw it somewhere, But without short cut it still doesn't work

Comment: @xbonez; Why does it need to be icon and not shortcut icon? Microsoft's IE Documentation states that it should be shortcut icon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx - I am using the code on their dev centre website and it won't even work in IE.

Comment: Just tried "icon". Still doesn't work. Not even after clearing cache, and browsing history.

Comment: This is wrong. The MSDN website has in their source code: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{path to icon}" />` and it works fine.