# Favicon is not visible on my hosting

Tags: phpbb3

I have added a favicon in a phpbb forum.

[image]

I can clearly see it in the view source but the tab still shows the hostgator's favicon, I tried hard refresh as well. It didn't work.

The same favicon is working fine another app.

What's the reason behind disappearance of favicon?

I click on the link directly from view source, I can see the icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [favicon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797094/favicon-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's dev tools console and see if there are any clues there - maybe the icon is in a different folder than what you're pointing to, in which case you'd expect to see a 404 or similar error there.

If you don't see one, maybe it's the placement of the tag? These kinds of icon links generally go in the `head` of the page and yours appears to be stuck somewhere in the middle of the `body` code. Try moving it up there, and make sure you don't have an existing `shortcut icon` tag up in the head already.

Comment: fixed it, got the issue.